# jersey restful webservice tomcat version

Tags: tomcat, java, jersey

I want to write a simple restful webservice. As it would be as simple as accessing data from / to the database, I am planning to use tomcat & not any heavy application server. I have existing tomcat 5.5 setup. Which Jersey version would be compatible with tomcat 5.5 & java 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

jersey-bundle-1.1.5.1 works with JDK 1.5 and Tomcat 5.5

Comment: thanks Josek. Right now, i have configured jersey 1.1.5.1 with Tomcat 6, Java 1.5 and Eclipselink. Do you foresee any problem with this?